# I can not find a way to put new content in a another element by clicking a element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I hope someone could explain to me how to script a button element on my web page.

I am new to javascript and html. So I hope what I'm asking makes sense.

The idea is that the contents of an element changes to content obtained from a php file on the server.

I am using php to serve html5. I have tried the following:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementByID("myID").innerHTML(src="_document_with_new_content.php")") class="myClass"></a>.
```

my results are that the styles on my elements are lost and the desired elements do not load into the container element.

I also get no success from the ajax:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementByID("myID").load(src="_document_with_new_content.php")></a>
```

I am obviously doing it wrong, but can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Ajax but the code in your example was slightly wrong.

How about something like this?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         $("a#some-identifier").on("click", function(e){         
              $( "#myID" ).load( "document_with_new_content.php" );
              e.preventDefault();
         });
    });
</script>
```

jQuery example and explanation below:

https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I also found a similar piece of useful information at http://icant.co.uk/articles/things-to-know-about-ajax/header-switching.html, and the solution in both cases do the trick for me. Much appreciated, really!

Comment: @user3464383 thanks. I'm glad you found it useful. If you could accept this as the answer then that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few things to mention:

1. Use single quotes for you javascript: `onclick="document.getElementById('myID')..."` instead of `onclick="document.getElementById("myID")..."`.
2. Javascript is case sensitive: So `document.getElementByID('myID')` won't work, but `document.getElementById('myID')` will.
3. innerHTML is not a function. This will work:

   ```
   <a onclick="document.getElementById('myID').innerHTML = 'this will load'" class="myClass">click here</a>
   <div id="myID"></div>
   ```
4. Loading an external document isn't that easy. If you simply want to learn some javascript, then I recommend to take a step back and start with the basics. But if you just want to build something quick, then have a look at a library like JQuery which is easy to learn and makes a lot of things a lot easier.

Hope this was useful.